# Look for a signature method similar to proxy resigning

Tags: bls-signature

The tag of a file is generated by the user's private key, which includes the file data, the file identifier and other contents. Is there any signature algorithm that can modify the file identifier information and regenerate the file signature under the original user's private key without disturbing the user?
I've seen Sanitizable signatures before, but this approach produces signatures that don't change numerically, which is not what I want.

Comment: The construction $\operatorname{Sign}(\mathsf{Priv},(\mathsf{data},\mathsf{id},\mathsf{other}))=\operatorname{Sign-Ed25519}(\mathsf{Priv},\operatorname{size}(\mathsf{data})\|\mathsf{data}\|\mathsf{other})\mathbin\|\mathsf{id}$ seems to ticks all the question's goals. Notice that changing $\mathsf{id}$ is possible without the private key, and changes the signature. If that construction is not acceptable, please [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/109316/edit) the question to define the goals more precisely.